# how to save all the generated image in a folder in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to use data augmentation with pytorch. I want to save all the generated images in a folder (`target_dir`) with different numbering based on the batch index.

Here is my code. I am using `epoch=100` and `batch_size=128`.

```py
import os



for batch_idx in range(BATCH_SIZE):
    
torchvision.utils.save_image(img_grid_fake, f"C:/UserspythonProjectgenerated_image/Fake_image%{batch_idx}d.png", global_step=step)
```

but i am only getting last 128 generated images, previous generated image are get deleted when next epoch run.

Comment: What is the variable img_grid_fake expected to be? each image in the batch?

Comment: `img_grid_fake = torchvision.utils.make_grid(
                    fake[:1], normalize=True
                )`

Comment: i want to save all image but i don't know why previous images get deleted

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the images with `f"Fake_image-{epoch}-{batch-idx}.png"` so that both `epoch` and `batch_idx` are used in naming the files.

```py
import os
import torch
from torch import nn
import torchvision
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor

target_dir = r"C:/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/generated/generated_image/"

EPOCHS = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 64
GRID_SIZE = 9 # 9 images in each grid
NUM_ROWS = 3 # sqrt(GRID_SIZE)

# if you want all the images in a batch to make the image-grid, 
# set GRID_SIZE = BATCH_SIZE

train_dataset = YourFakeImageDataset()
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
                              shuffle=True, transform=ToTensor())

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    for batch_idx, (X, y) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        # assume X is the fake-image returned by the dataloader
        # and y is some target value for the X, also returned by the dataloader

        # ... do something with your images here
        # B, C, H, W = X.shape
        img_grid_fake = torchvision.utils.make_grid(X[:GRID_SIZE, ...], nrow=NUM_ROWS)
        filepath = os.path.join(target_dir, f"Fake_image-{epoch}-{batch_idx}.png")
        torchvision.utils.save_image(img_grid_fake, filepath)
```

**NOTE**: I cannot answer you properly, as your question does not specify a lot of details clearly (some of them are asked by others in the comments).

If you are making a fake-image-grid, how are you doing that? With `torchvision.utils.make_grid()`?

#### References

- [`torchvision.utils.make_grid()`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.utils.make_grid.html)
- [Visualizing a grid of images](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/auto_examples/plot_visualization_utils.html#visualizing-a-grid-of-images)
- [`torchvision.utils.make_grid()`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.utils.make_grid.html)

Comment: i had tried your code but only images for lastest epoch are saved. no previous images are there.

Comment: yes i am using totchvision.utils.make_grid() for fake-image-grid

Comment: @sid1994s You might have tried before I made the latest changes. Could you please try again and let me know here?

Comment: Thank you sir for your help and time. But I am still getting same issue.

Comment: @sid1994s Please try it now. I made some changes. But cannot run the code and test it. I will leave the testing to you. Typically, if you are asking any question, always try to give the data necessary for the code as a part of the question. If you have a snippet that loads the data, then it's the best. This reduces the amount of time people have to spend to answer your question. After all, anybody who helps you, does it for free (to you) and to a loss of personal time (for him/her). So, making sure ease of running your code and loading data will get you working answers rather quickly.